Inline edit save not working in multiple repeater
The code is just a simple widget. Here just i added two repeaters with a text control which i want to edit in inline. Now in the widget inline editing is working fine but it can't saved.
But when i use one repeater only then it's perfectly working the inline edit and save.
Now I used this add_inline_editing_attributes for inline editing. So to save the inline edit text for two repeaters what should i do?
protected function register_controls() {
    $this->start_controls_section(
        'content_section',
        [
            'label' => esc_html__( 'Test Plugin', 'test-plugin-td' ),
            'tab' => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::TAB_CONTENT,
        ]
    );

    $repeater = new Repeater();
    $repeater->add_control(
        'text',
        [
            'label' => __( 'Business Hour', 'test-plugin-td' ),
            'type' => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::TEXT,
            'label_block' => true,
            'placeholder' => __( 'First Name', 'test-plugin-td' ),
            'default' => __( 'First Name', 'test-plugin-td' ),
            'dynamic' => [
                'active' => true,
            ],
        ]
    );
    $this->add_control(
        'business_hours',
        [
            'label' => __( 'Test Plugin', 'test-plugin-td' ),
            'type' => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::REPEATER,
            'fields' => $repeater->get_controls(),
            'default' => [
                [
                    'text' => __( 'First Name', 'test-plugin-td' ),
                ],
                [
                    'text' => __( 'Last Name', 'test-plugin-td' ),
                ],
            ],
            'title_field' => '{{{ text }}}',
        ]
    );

    $this->end_controls_section();


    $this->start_controls_section(
        'content_2section',
        [
            'label' => esc_html__( 'Test Plugin', 'test-plugin-td' ),
            'tab' => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::TAB_CONTENT,
        ]
    );

    $repeskeater = new Repeater();
    $repeskeater->add_control(
        'text2',
        [
            'label' => __( 'Business Hour', 'test-plugin-td' ),
            'type' => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::TEXT,
            'label_block' => true,
            'placeholder' => __( 'First Name', 'test-plugin-td' ),
            'default' => __( 'First Name', 'test-plugin-td' ),
            'dynamic' => [
                'active' => true,
            ],
        ]
    );
    $this->add_control(
        'business_2hours',
        [
            'label' => __( 'Test Plugin', 'test-plugin-td' ),
            'type' => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::REPEATER,
            'fields' => $repeskeater->get_controls(),
            'default' => [
                [
                    'text' => __( 'First Name', 'test-plugin-td' ),
                ],
                [
                    'text' => __( 'Last Name', 'test-plugin-td' ),
                ],
            ],
            'title_field' => '{{{ text2 }}}',
        ]
    );

    $this->end_controls_section();
}

protected function render() {
    $settings = $this->get_settings_for_display();
    echo '<ul class="test-plugin-td">';
    foreach ( $settings['business_hours'] as $index => $item ) :
        $text_key = $this->get_repeater_setting_key( 'text', 'business_hours', $index );
        $this->add_inline_editing_attributes( $text_key );
        ?>
        <li class="business-hour-item">
            <span <?php $this->print_render_attribute_string( $text_key ); ?>>
                <?php echo esc_html( $item['text'] ); ?>
            </span>
        </li>
        <?php
    endforeach;
    echo '</ul>';

    echo '<ul class="test-plugin-td">';
    foreach ( $settings['business_2hours'] as $index => $item ) :
        $text_key = $this->get_repeater_setting_key( 'text2', 'business_2hours', $index );
        $this->add_inline_editing_attributes( $text_key );
        ?>
        <li class="business-hour-item">
            <span <?php $this->print_render_attribute_string( $text_key ); ?>>
                <?php echo esc_html( $item['text2'] ); ?>
            </span>
        </li>
        <?php
    endforeach;
    echo '</ul>';
}


I suggest some fixes:

Use Unique Keys for Repeaters:
Each repeater's items must have distinct keys to avoid conflicts. Ensure the control keys like 'text' and 'text2' are unique in their respective repeaters.

Register Inline Editing for Correct Keys:
When you call add_inline_editing_attributes, you must ensure it refers to the appropriate repeater and control keys.

Ensure Repeater Setting Keys Are Unique:
Use get_repeater_setting_key appropriately to register inline editing attributes for each specific repeater and control.


And updated the render function:
protected function render() {
$settings = $this->get_settings_for_display();

// Render the first repeater
echo '<ul class="test-plugin-td">';
foreach ( $settings['business_hours'] as $index => $item ) {
    $text_key = $this->get_repeater_setting_key( 'text', 'business_hours', $index );
    $this->add_inline_editing_attributes( $text_key, 'none' );
    ?>
    <li class="business-hour-item">
        <span <?php $this->print_render_attribute_string( $text_key ); ?>>
            <?php echo esc_html( $item['text'] ); ?>
        </span>
    </li>
    <?php
}
echo '</ul>';

// Render the second repeater
echo '<ul class="test-plugin-td">';
foreach ( $settings['business_2hours'] as $index => $item ) {
    $text2_key = $this->get_repeater_setting_key( 'text2', 'business_2hours', $index );
    $this->add_inline_editing_attributes( $text2_key, 'none' );
    ?>
    <li class="business-hour-item">
        <span <?php $this->print_render_attribute_string( $text2_key ); ?>>
            <?php echo esc_html( $item['text2'] ); ?>
        </span>
    </li>
    <?php
}
echo '</ul>';}

